# error while creating multiple mysql servers on same ubuntu machine

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

While creating multiple mysql servers on same ubuntu machine under EC2 instance on AWS.I successfully created /var/lib/mysql2 , /var/log/mysql2 ,/etc/mysql2/
done desired changes in my.cnf file(under /etc/mysql2/ which i created by just copying /etc/mysql/ content) along with desired rights to mysql user

(Reference used to do the needful :-- 
 - http://www.ducea.com/2009/01/19/running-multiple-instances-of-mysql-on-the-same-machine/
)

After running the following

```
sed -i 's/3306/3307/g' my.cnf
sed -i 's/mysqld.sock/mysqld2.sock/g' my.cnf
sed -i 's/mysqld.pid/mysqld2.pid/g' my.cnf
sed -i 's/var\/lib\/mysql/var\/lib\/mysql2/g' my.cnf
sed -i 's/var\/log\/mysql/var\/log\/mysql2/g' my.cnf
```

Proceeded by running the following command where i am getting error

```
mysql_install_db --user=mysql --datadir=/var/lib/mysql2/
```

**Error:--->
FATAL ERROR: Could not find my-default.cnf file in my system and found the path 
If you compiled from source, you need to run 'make install' to
copy the software into the correct location ready for operation.
If you are using a binary release, you must either be at the top
level of the extracted archive, or pass the --basedir option
pointing to that location.**

I tried to do the following but in vain

```
sudo mysql_install_db --user=mysql --datadir=/var/lib/mysql2/ --basedir=/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.6/examples/
```

**FATAL ERROR: Could not find /fill_help_tables.sql
If you compiled from source, you need to run 'make install' to
copy the software into the correct location ready for operation.
If you are using a binary release, you must either be at the top
level of the extracted archive, or pass the --basedir option
pointing to that location.**

Please help in resolving the issue.I have installed MySQL server 5.6 and want to use the same version for my another instance on 3307 port